# extracting specific substrings from string

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a bash script. In a directory I have 2 fastq files:

`A-122-3.BH7WBVADXX.lane_1_P1_I24.hg19.sequence.fastq`

`A-122-3.BH7WBVADXX.lane_1_P2_I24.hg19.sequence.fastq`

I just want to loop on P1 lets say something like this

```
for f in *_P1*
do
   SOMETHING
done
```

Now In SOMETHING part I want to define some varables which i would be using later in my code
I need to extract these values from my string:
`A-122-3.BH7WBVADXX.lane_1_P1_I24.hg19.sequence.fastq`

I need `ID = A-122-3-BH7WBVADXX-1`

I need `PU = BH7WBVADXX`

I need `LB = A-122-3`

Then I will solve it further.

NOTE : FILENAME ARE NOT OF SAME LENGTH. **A-122-3** PART VARIES FOR DIFFERENT SAMPLES AND ALSO THIS PART **I24** VARIES.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each filename you are processing has the same length and that each substring has the same length, you can split based on this. Also,  sure where the `-1` part on the `ID` comes from, so I assume you get it from `lane_1`.

```
for file in *_P1*
do
  id=${file:0:18}-${file:24:1}
  pu=${file:8:10}
  lb=${file:0:7}

  echo "id=$id pu=$pu lb=$lb"
done
```

#### Update

This should work provided certain dots and underscores remain consistent:

```
for file in *_P1*
do
  lb=${file%%.*}

  pu=${file%%.lane_*}
  pu=${pu#*.}

  num=${file%%_P*}
  num=${num##*_}

  id="$lb-$pu-$num"

  echo "id=$id pu=$pu lb=$lb"
done
```

Comment: Hi, I am afraid but each filename does not have same length. I should have mentioned that before. Fixing. You are correct, 1 comes from lane_1

Comment: @user3138373, updated.